# Why do I have to click the Tab button twice before it responds?

Tags: angular, typescript

Am working with a Tabbed Form with jQuery Functionality in Angular 4. My Tabbed Form works but I noticed I have to click the Tab Button twice before it responds. Below is the snippet:

**TS**

```
declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular App';

  toggleEvent() {
    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
      $('.container').stop().addClass('active');
    });
    $('.close').on('click', function() {
      $('.container').stop().removeClass('active');
    });

  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="card alt" (click)="toggleEvent()">
..
..
</div>
```

So you know, I have added jQuery functionality to my Angular 4, since am just trying to bring in a Bootstrap (HTML, CSS, JS) App into Angular 4, so as to make my Tabbed Form work as it is working perfectly in bootstrap.

**But why do I have to click the Tab Button twice before it works?** I have checked and I do not know what am missing here.

Comment: And now I do not know why someone has to mark me down here.

Comment: Because instead of writing your code, you linked to another page. Put the code in your question.

Comment: I linked to my code and solution. Why do I have to be DRY? Someone out here would say I should have linked to the solution instead. Besides your purpose of marking in down has nothing to do with Research Effort

Comment: First of all, I'm not the one who marked you down. Secondly, marking someone down doesn't necessarily have to be about research effort. Third of all, if you need help it is your responsibility to provide the detail of your problem in the easiest and most convenient way for the person answering to be able to help you. Being linked to yet another SO article is not the most convenient thing in the world.

Comment: Alright. Its okay.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: You have to click on element to call your function that is waiting for another click to execute code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have figured it out and I think posting what I used will help so many people. I figured out the first click initialises and the second takes the action. To better solve that, I used Angular `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook. Instead of creating a new click event, I wrapped the jQuery inside `ngOnInit()` such that the TS file becomes:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
      $('.container').stop().addClass('active');
    });
    $('.close').on('click', function() {
      $('.container').stop().removeClass('active');
    });
  }

}
```

With this you do not need to add any click event into your HTML file. HTML becomes:

```
<div class="card alt">
..
..
</div>
```

`ngOnInit()` Initializes the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties, which will make this work immediately the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing this problem because you are trying to archive this with multiple libraries that are at loggerhead. You can either abandon JQuery altogether and write this implementation with pure Angular-Typescript or use JQuery instead to archive this without Angular interfering.

With this, it is difficult to pinpoint where the problem is coming from and how best to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Angular you're using, but you shouldn't have to use jQuery for something this simple. Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="card alt" (click)="toggleEvent()">
    <div class="container" [class.active]="active">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular App';
  active = true;

  toggleEvent(){
     this.active = !this.active;
  }     
}
```

This is simplified, though, as each "Tab" should be a component with its own "active" bool. The App Component should only hold a list of different "Tab" components.

On to your actual question, though, it's probably because you're calling the function in `(click)="toggleEvent()"` via angular, and inside your function you're also calling the JQuery `.on('click', function())`, thus requiring two clicks before a response. Delete the `.on('click') JQuery from your code and it should only require one click.

Comment: This wont work. Angular will complain about unresolved `active` variable and you have to add `this` to `active = !active;` such that you will have `this.active = !this.active;`

Comment: Edit and post the entire html, or at least the elements containing .close and .toggle.

Comment: I have fixed it. Thank you for the effort.